# Create bigrams using a list of unigrams

Tags: nlp, nltk, gensim

I have a list of unigrams
`

```
[('bottom', 507.95),
 ('straight', 426.5),
 ('comment', 415.5),
 ('wearing', 398.55),
 ('room', 397.85),
 ('wondering', 396.85),
 ('difficult', 382.85),
 ('sleeping', 381.65),
 ('comments', 381.1),
 ('looked', 379.0),
 ('interest', 378.2),
 ('missing', 373.5),
 ('harder', 373.1),
 ('planning', 370.05),
 ('answer', 367.15),
 ('allowed', 364.85),
 ('bunch', 361.0),
 ('recommend', 360.45),
 ('worst', 359.3),
 ('technically', 359.15)]
```

`

And a I have to make bigrams with this words, the function nltk.bigrams would output (bottom straight), (straight comment), etc. I don't know if is possible to form all the different bigrams and discard the ones that does not  have sense, for example "difficult sleeping" has more sense that have "wearing comments".

For the moment I was thinking using gensim but I did not fin a functions that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Generating *every* possible bigram from those words is easy - though if you have *N* words, that will be *N^2* bigrams, and most of them *won't* be bigrams that sensibly represent pairs in real texts.

More typical is to start from a corpus of real, meaningful texts – and then collect/count the bigrams that actually appear. And in general, frequency of natural usage is the true best indicator of a bigram's 'sensibility'.

If for some reason you really needed to take *random* bigrams, and assess whether they represent reasonable concepts or might appear in some real natural texts, and you don't have your own corpora, there might be some roundabout heuristics that could be used, perhaps using data from *other* sources (that have themselves been hand-created or trained from large corpora). But that's not a usual exercise, nor set of constraints... so to get more suggestions it'd help for you to say more why you have such a peculiar goal.

Comment: I'm doing classification of depression, I use two type of list that are my "dictionaries" of words that I use for the BOW construction, I am doing the baseline and some of the best result with the implementation of sklearn  has bigrams and trigrams. So, to see if the words that I used as dictionary are good is necesarry form them in to bigrams.

Comment: But why create bigrams from a mere list-of-unigrams, instead of a real corpus representing actual unigram-to-unigram cooccurrences? Again, that's the typical approach, including in `sklearn`: observing real bigrams in some actual training corpus. Not: trying to deduce which arbitrary pairings might make sense or not.